# Theorem 2.4(b) in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-varieties

I've been staring at this for a while, and I'm failing to see why $\phi^*=\iota$ in the proof of (b).

Let $f\in K(C_2)$, I tried to calculate both sides, and got stuck.
$$ \phi^*f = f\circ \phi= f([1:\iota(g_1):\dots:\iota(g_N)]) \overset{?}{=} \iota(f) $$
Any help is appreciated! I feel like I'm just misunderstanding a definition or something.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possibly the abuse of notation is confusing: Let $g\in K(C_2)$ and $z\in C_2$, then $g(z)=g([1:g_1(z):...:g_N(z)])$ where on the right hand side we have identified $C_2$ with its image in the projective space

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is it because $\iota$ fixes $K$ so we have that $\iota(f([1:g_1:...:g_n])) = f([1:\iota(g_1):...:\iota(g_n)])$ because $f$ can be written as a quotient of polynomials with $K$ coefficients?